# Transformar cadena de mysql en una lista personalizada

Tags: php, mysql

con mysql genero esta cadena:

```
(1) jugo mixto{~~~}2:1{~~~_~~~}(1) pan con pollo{~~~}1:1
```

donde:

- `{~~~_~~~}` separa los pedidos (pedido1{~~~*~~~}pedido2{~~~*~~~}pedido3)
- `{~~~}` separa el plato de los agregados (plato 1{~~~}maca,chorizo)
- y **n1:n2** donde n1 es el id del agregado y n2 es la cantidad

yo lo quiero en este formato:

PLATO ( #cantidad de agregado **agregado**,#cantidad de agregado **agregado**)

PLATO 2 (#cantidad de agregado **agregado** )

Lo que yo e hecho:
Escaneo todos los agregados en mi base de datos(pocos), luego los recorro y los almaceno en un array con el indice del id del agregado:

```
$bd_agregados = $bd->query("SELECT id_agregado,agregado FROM agregados")->fetch_all();
$cuantos_bd_agregados = count($bd_agregados);
for ($for_agregados=0; $for_agregados < $cuantos_bd_agregados; $for_agregados++) {
$agregado_in[$bd_agregados[$for_agregados][0]] = array("id"=>$bd_agregados[$for_agregados][0],"nombre"=>$bd_agregados[$for_agregados][1]);
}
```

cosa que asi voy a tener esto: agregado_in[id_del_agregado]["nombre"] = agregado; y asi puedo acceder al nombre del agregado solo con su id.
una vez almacenado todos mis agregados en un array creo una funcion para "explodear" cada item de mis pedidos:

```
function transSQL($text,$datarray=null){
$expl_one = explode("{~~~_~~~}",$text);
foreach ($expl_one as $value) {
    $expl_tmp = explode("{~~~}",$value);
        echo "<li><b>".$expl_tmp[0]."</b>";
    if(strlen($expl_tmp[1])>=2){
        echo " (";
        $ex_tm2 = explode("-",$expl_tmp[1]);
       foreach ($ex_tm2 as $v2) {
           $ex_tm3 = explode(":",$v2);
           echo "<b>".$ex_tm3[1]."</b> ".$datarray[$ex_tm3[0]]["nombre"].", ";
       }
        echo ")";
    }
    echo "</li>";
}
}
```

Esta funcion recive 2 parametros:

1. la cadena generada por mysql: (1) jugo mixto{~~~}2:1{~~~_~~~}(1) pan con pollo{~~~}1:1
2. el array donde estan todos los agregados ($agregados_in)

todo funciona pero me parece que estoy consumiendo demaciados recursos en cada explode

Comment: Si tu preocupación es la optimización, vayamos más lejos, al **origen mismo de los datos**. ¿Esto existe en la base de datos: `{~~~_~~~}` y también esto: `{~~~}`, y además de eso hay también datos separados por esto: `~`? Si la respuesta es sí, ¿por qué existe? ¿por qué no empiezas a normalizar, limpiar tus datos en la BD misma? Si la respuesta es no, entonces ya hablaremos sobre cómo mejorar el código...

Comment: @A.Cedano no amigo esos datos no existen en mi base de datos, yo uso Concat() mysql para juntarlos en uno solo y uso esos separadadores para poder mas adelante dividirlos y mostrarlos mas ordenados

Comment: No entiendo mucho entonces por qué te complicas. ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de los datos en si mismos? ¿Por qué mejor no generar una estructura ordenada (JSON por ejemplo) que puedas leer luego fácilmente?